# Issue with ViewBag in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, viewbag

In my simple ASP.NET application with MVC I'm trying use ViewBag.
In my view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SomeSampleText";
}
```

works.

But if I want to set `ViewBag.Message = "SomeText"` in controller it's null and after this in view it's also null.
Anyway InteliSence like `@ViewBag` or `@model` also not works.

Comment: where is it `null` ? In the view rendered by that action method ?

Comment: This looks fine. Have you set the value in controller?

Comment: Please specify properly where you get the `null`??

Comment: Null issue fixed, but still problems in view. Please check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was null in View. I thougth the cause is missing some references, but it was spelling mistake in controller.

It's works but still I've issue with "red" `@ViewBag` and `@model` and missing InteliSence. It's not working also with all asp TagHelpers (I've proper dependencies and they work).
I want to add I created project from empty Asp.NET core template, not from Web Application or MVC templates.